# Possible to call multiple AWS Lambda aliases from one API Gateway stage?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Is it possible for one stage in the API Gateway to be able to call different Lambda aliases based on the API Gateway URL? All I have found so far is where you can point a given API Gateway stage to a single Lambda alias using stage variables. What I want is something like the PROD stage to be able to call different aliases. Example call:

https://xyz.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Prod/v1

or

https://xyz.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Prod/v2

Possible?

Answer (score 1):

The links which you provided are for an API with a **single stage** called `Prod` and **two resources** called `v1` and `v2`:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Thus you could **set integration** for each resource (`v1` and `v2`) to different alias of the same lambda function. This would result in the API links you described in the question.